# Error No matching function for call to 'getline'

Tags: c++, string, char, whitespace, cin

I'm currently using XCODE to program in C++ and I ran in this error:

> no matching function for call to 'getline'

I do not know why. Can anyone help?

What I'm basically trying to do is get input from the user that also includes spaces when they type in the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

//Maxium numbers of exams//
#define MAX_EXAMS 30

using namespace std;

//defined type exam which is a struct composed of three elements//
typedef struct exam{
    char name[100];
    char date[100];
    int mark;
}exam_t;

//global array that can be accessed everywhere//
exam_t exams[MAX_EXAMS];
//function to move exams to the next position in the global array//
void MovePreviousExam(){
    exam_t last = exams[MAX_EXAMS - 1];
    for (int i = MAX_EXAMS; i > 0; i--) {
        exams[i] = exams[i - 1];
    }
    exams[0] = last;
}

int main() {
    //Used to check what the user wants//
    bool doesUserWantToViewExams = false;
    bool doesUserWantToEnterExam = false;
    int insertion = 0;
    //The loop is used to keep the program going until the user decides to stop it//
    do {
        cout << "You want to view exams? Press 1.\nYou want to enter an exam? Press 2.\nYou want to close program? Press 3.\n";
        cin >> insertion;
        //Checking insertion and enabling variables//
        if (insertion ==  1) {
            doesUserWantToViewExams = true;
        }else if(insertion == 2){
            doesUserWantToEnterExam = true;
        }else if(insertion == 3){
            cout << "Goodbye :)\n";
        }else{
            cout << "Unkown Value, try again.\n";
        }
        //Done with the conditions, use if else statements to execute selected task.//
        if (doesUserWantToViewExams == true && doesUserWantToEnterExam == false){
            cout << "Here are your exams:\n";
        }
        
        if (doesUserWantToEnterExam == true && doesUserWantToViewExams == false) {
            //Since the user will add more exams, this function will move the previous to the next spot in the array//
            MovePreviousExam();
            //Enter exam//
            cout << "Enter your exam's name, date and grade in this order:\n";
            
            getline(cin, exams[0].name, "\n");
            getline(cin, exams[0].date, "\n");
            getline(cin, exams[0].mark, "\n");
            
            }
    } while (insertion != 3);
    //Code block to determine what the user wants to select//

    return 0;
}
```

Just letting you know, I'm a starter at C++, so I'm really not the best at it.

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, first of all please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question. It usually contains hints and other information that could help solving the problem. Also please add comments in the shown code where you get the errors. And if possible, please try to condense the code into a proper [mre] to show us (and show us the errors from that example).

Comment: `std::getline` - Defined in header `<string>` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: As a hint: There's a difference between [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (which you use) and [`istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). I recommend you continue to use `std::getline` but start using the C++ class `std::string` for all your strings.

Comment: A string with one character, like `"\n"`, is not the same as a single character, like `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

**getline()** reads characters from an input stream (cin) and places them into a **string** (for more info [visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline))

I use stoi() method to make **int** from **string**

So change the types of variables in your structure:

```
typedef struct exam{
    string name;
    string date;
    int mark;
}exam_t;
```

And the input code throughout the program ( I recommend using only getline() in your program )

```
string tmp;
getline(cin, tmp, '\n');
insertion = stoi(tmp);
```

and

```
getline(cin, exams[0].name, '\n');
getline(cin, exams[0].date, '\n');
getline(cin, tmp, '\n');
exams[0].mark = stoi(tmp);
```

Now, you have to work a little bit with **True/False Flags** so that your program works properly. **Good Luck!**

Comment: The newline `'\n'` is the default line terminator got `std::getline`, it's not needed to explicitly add it as an argument.